# Using .htaccess file to redirect to a subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my root folder, I have a home directory. I'd like all requests for mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com to be forwarded to home.mydomain.com. In my cPanel, I have already set up the sub-domain home.mydomain.com to point to mydomain.com/home.

Here's what I currently have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \/home\/$1 [L]
```

This successfully forwards mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/home or www.mydomain.com/home, respectively. But home.mydomain.com/filename gives me an internal server error, instead of serving the file at mydomain.com/home/filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the exact requirements, but it seems you want to rewrite all (www.)mydomain.com requests to the /home directory while your subdomain home.mydomain.com *already* points to that directory and thus should be exempt from that rewrite directive. If for some reason (www.)mydomain.com can't be set up to point to /home as well, you'd need a Rewrite Condition, something like

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1 [L]
```

I also removed the backslashes which should not be needed. You can use the [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) to check rewrite rules easily online.